# Using nonce in menu item

Tags: menus, nonce

I have a log out link in the main header menu, when you click on the link to log out, you are redirected to the page asking if you really want to log out. I know it's doing this because there is no nonce in the menu URL.

My question is: is it even possible to add a nonce in CMS appearance>menus in the edit menus screen? The url is something like: `example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http://example.com/myaccount/&_wpnonce=`

Just for giggles I tried adding `wp_create_nonce('logout')` to the end but of course it doesn't' work.

If this isn't possible is there another way to bypass the 'are you sure you want to log out' screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a filter:

```
function change_menu($items){
  foreach($items as $item){
    if( $item->title == "Log Out"){
         $item->url = $item->url . "&_wpnonce=" . wp_create_nonce( 'log-out' );
    }
  }
  return $items;

}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu');
```

Comment: This works for me!